# Tabla HTML supera el ancho que se le asigna

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<table class="TblReporte" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">RETIRO</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">CAJA GENERAL</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">RETIRO SUCURSAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td border="1">NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE</td>
        <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
        <td border="1">MONTO</td>
        <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
        <td border="1">MONTO</td>
        <td border="1">COMENTARIO O JUSTIFICANTE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Las columnas las cargo por *Base de Datos*, en la columa comentarios necesito agregar mucha información pero, al momento de hacerlo la tabla se expande demaciado provocando que aparezca  un `ScrollBar`, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definiendo el ancho de la celda a 1px se mantiene el ancho de la columna

```css
table {max-width:99.5%;}
td {
  width: 1px
}
```

```html
<table class="TblReporte" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">RETIRO</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">CAJA GENERAL</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">RETIRO SUCURSAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td border="1">NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE</td>
    <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
    <td border="1">MONTO</td>
    <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
    <td border="1">MONTO</td>
    <td border="1">COMENTARIO O JUSTIFICANTE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Aunque sería recomendable usar anchos mínimos y máximos para tener mejor control

```css
table {max-width:99.5%;}
td {
font-size :12px;
  width: 1px;
}

.anchocontrolado {
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 250px
}
```

```html
<table class="TblReporte" border="1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">RETIRO</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">CAJA GENERAL</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">RETIRO SUCURSAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td border="1">NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE</td>
    <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
    <td border="1">MONTO</td>
    <td border="1">OPERACIONES</td>
    <td border="1">MONTO</td>
    <td border="1" class="anchocontrolado">COMENTARIO O JUSTIFICANTE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td border="1">blablablabla</td>
    <td border="1">blablabla</td>
    <td border="1">blabla blablabla bla blablablabla bla</td>
    <td border="1">blablablabla</td>
    <td border="1">bla</td>
    <td border="1" class="anchocontrolado">Mínimo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td border="1">blablablabla</td>
    <td border="1">blablabla</td>
    <td border="1">blabla</td>
    <td border="1">blablablabla</td>
    <td border="1">bla</td>
    <td border="1" class="anchocontrolado">Activa Máximo blablabla bla blablablabla bla blablablabla bla blablablabla bla blablablabla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```